# Rotate Photoshop Text With Script From Starting Point Of Text

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I am rotating a text layer using the script below
It rotates from the middle point of the text
Is there a way in script to rotate from the left (starting point) of the text?

```
var idRtte = charIDToTypeID( "Rtte" );
    var desc199 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
        var ref15 = new ActionReference();
        var idLyr = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
        var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
        var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
        ref15.putEnumerated( idLyr, idOrdn, idTrgt );
    desc199.putReference( idnull, ref15 );
    var idAngl = charIDToTypeID( "Angl" );
    var idAng = charIDToTypeID( "#Ang" );
    desc199.putUnitDouble( idAngl, idAng, rotation);
executeAction( idRtte, desc199, DialogModes.NO );
```

Comment: This code seems to be from ScriptingListener: just record an action of you rotating the text the way you want and you'll see all the descriptors you need to add to define a pivot point

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy it is from ScriptingListener. But I see no option in Photoshop to set the pivot point like in Illustrator. Are you saying there is that option?

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy never mind I found it. If you want to add an answer I will mark it as correct so you get the credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photoshop uses an additional descriptor to define a pivot point: there are several hardcoded strings for layer corners and a more extended descriptor for custom pivot points that use 2 absolute coordinates.

Predefined corners:

```
// 'Qcs0' top left
// 'Qcs7' middle left
// 'Qcs3' bottom left

// 'Qcs4' top center
// 'Qcsa' middle center
// 'Qcs6' bottom center

// 'Qcs1' top right
// 'Qcs5' middle right
// 'Qcs2' bottom right

function rotatePivot(pivot, angle)
{
  var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
  var ref = new ActionReference();
  ref.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), charIDToTypeID('Ordn'), charIDToTypeID('Trgt'));
  desc.putReference(charIDToTypeID('null'), ref);
  desc.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID('FTcs'), charIDToTypeID('QCSt'), charIDToTypeID(pivot));
  desc.putUnitDouble(charIDToTypeID('Angl'), charIDToTypeID('#Ang'), angle);
  executeAction(charIDToTypeID('Trnf'), desc, DialogModes.NO);
} // end of rotatePivot()

rotatePivot('Qcs3', 45);
```

Custom pivot. `pivotCoords` is an array of absolute coordinates.

```
// 'Qcsi' custom pivot
function rotateCustomPivot(pivotCoords, angle)
{
  var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
  var ref = new ActionReference();
  ref.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), charIDToTypeID('Ordn'), charIDToTypeID('Trgt'));
  desc.putReference(charIDToTypeID('null'), ref);
  desc.putEnumerated(charIDToTypeID('FTcs'), charIDToTypeID('QCSt'), charIDToTypeID('Qcsi'));
  var descPivot = new ActionDescriptor();
  descPivot.putUnitDouble(charIDToTypeID('Hrzn'), charIDToTypeID('#Pxl'), pivotCoords[0]);
  descPivot.putUnitDouble(charIDToTypeID('Vrtc'), charIDToTypeID('#Pxl'), pivotCoords[1]);
  desc.putObject(charIDToTypeID('Pstn'), charIDToTypeID('Pnt '), descPivot);
  desc.putUnitDouble(charIDToTypeID('Angl'), charIDToTypeID('#Ang'), angle);
  executeAction(charIDToTypeID('Trnf'), desc, DialogModes.NO);
} // end of rotateCustomPivot()

// b[0] and b[3] are bottom-left coord of a layer,
// so this will rotate using a custom point 
// that's 10 pixels away from that coord by x and y
var b = activeDocument.activeLayer.bounds;
var x = b[0] - 10;
var y = b[3] + 10;
rotateCustomPivot([x, y], 45);
```